# Is it a bug of the 'wait' method of gevent.event.Event?

Tags: python-2.7, gevent

I wrote a script to play with **gevent.event.Event** but I found that the *wait* method seems not take effect. The version of gevent I use is 1.0.

My script is the following and you can also get it [here](https://gist.github.com/flyer103/7819834):

```
#!/urs/bin/env python2.7
#coding: utf-8

"""Test the usage of 'gevent.event.Event' class.
"""

import random

import gevent
from gevent.event import Event


class TestEvent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = Event()

    def run(self):
        producers = [gevent.spawn(self._producer, i) for i in xrange(3)]
        consumers = [gevent.spawn(self._consumer, i) for i in xrange(3)]
        tasks     = []
        tasks.extend(producers)
        tasks.extend(consumers)
        gevent.joinall(tasks)

    def _producer(self, pid):
        print("I'm producer %d and now I don't want consume to do something" % (pid,))
        self.event.clear()
        sleeptime = random.randint(0, 5) * 0.01
        print("Sleeping time is %f" % (sleeptime, ))
        gevent.sleep(sleeptime)
        print("I'm producer %d and now consumer could do something." % (pid,))
        self.event.set()

    def _consumer(self, pid):
        print("I'm consumer %d and now I'm waiting for producer" % (pid,))
        flag = self.event.wait()
        print("I'm consumer %d. Flag is %r and now I can do something" % (pid, flag))
        self.event.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestEvent()
    test.run()
```

The output of the script is:
[image]

Comment: What did you expect? What is wrong with the output you got?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, if the **Event()._flag** is *False*, the *wait()* method should block the current greenlet but it shows not.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't? It's not clear why you find this surprising. Do you have any evidence that the consumer wasn't blocked at a time when the flag was true, in-between when it called wait and when wait returned?

Comment: I get the flag value in *_consumer* and then print it. The output shows that when the flag is *False*, the *_consumer* still runs rather than blocks.

Comment: You know two things: 1) The flag transitioned from true to false. 2) The thread woke up. From this, you conclude that the thread woke up while the flag was false. This conclusion is not supported by the evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your producers do the following:

P-A: Clear the event
P-B: Set the event

Your consumers do the following:

C-A: Wait for the event to become set
C-B: Wake up when event is set
C-C: Get the event value to return it
C-D: Clear the event

You enforce no ordering between your producer and your consumers or between your consumers and each other, so this can happen:

P-A (event is clear)
C1-A
C2-A
C3-A (all three consumers are waiting)
P-B (event is set)
C1-B
C2-B
C3-B (all consumers have woken up because the event is set)
C1-C (consumer 1 sees the event as set)
C1-D (consumer 1 has cleared the event)
C2-C (consumer 2 sees event as clear)
C3-C (consumer 3 sees event as clear)
C2-D
C3-D
...

Comment: Does it mean that if many consumers wait for the flag to be True and a producer sets the flag to be True, then all of the consumers wake up and don't be blocked any more and wait to be scheduled by *hub* greenlet even though other operations set the flag to be False?

Comment: Yes. When the event is set, all waiting greenlets are unblocked. When they wake up, the flag is what it is.